# Convergence of $\sum_n |\frac{\cos(3^n)}{n}|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So a recent post asked about convergence of  $\sum_n |\frac{\cos(2^n)}{n}|$, and using double-angle formula for $\cos$ it could be shown that for each pair of consecutive terms, at least one term had to satisfy $|\cos(2^n)| \geq \epsilon$ for some fixed universal $\epsilon > 0$, showing that the series diverges. This doesn't work for  $\sum_n |\frac{\cos(3^n)}{n}|$ though, because if $3^n$ is close to $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$ $\mod 2\pi$ then so is $3^{n+1}$. So how to determine convergence of  $\sum_n |\frac{\cos(3^n)}{n}|$? I'm almost certain the series diverges but the proof must be harder...

Comment: Just something that crossed my mind. I don't know if this helps: Is it possible to change variable $n$ to $log_3 x$?

Comment: Related question: is it possible to construct a number $a>0$ such that the series $\sum{|\cos{(a^n)}/n|}$ converges?

Comment: @user142299 Indeed, I could have asked the question for arbitrary $a$ but it seemed like $a = \pm 3$ is the hardest case because it gives arbitrarily long consecutive sub-sequences of coefficients $| \cos a^n|$ that are close to $0$.

Comment: It seems we will have to use some sort of lower bound on how well $\pi$ can be rationally approximated. I'm pretty sure the similar series $$\sum_n\left|\frac{\cos(3^n\cdot 2\alpha/\pi)}{n}\right|$$ where $\alpha$ is a base $3$ Louiville number should converge.

Comment: @AlexBecker That's a very interesting conjecture, I think worthy of another question where you are allowed to multiply $3^n$ by an arbitrary constant. I also think your idea of using a lower bound on how well $\pi$ can be rationally approximated is the way to go here. Just not sure how to make the proof work.

Comment: I searched the web a little looking for such a bound but came up empty.

Comment: According to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html), the irrationality exponent of $\pi$ is known to be finite, specifically $\mu(\pi)\le 7.6063$. This means that for any $\epsilon>0$, there are only finitely many rational numbers $p/q$ such that
$$\left|\pi-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^{\mu(\pi)+\epsilon}}$$
Thus for large $n$, taking $q+\epsilon=8$ and noting $q\ge 3^n$ we get that
$$\left|\frac{q\pi}{2}-3^n\right|\ge 3^{-7n}.$$ Unfortunately this bound is not good enough.